# Cannot issue AT Commands via Hyperterminal to 16 port wavecom gsm modem

Tags: gsm

I just have this GSM Model Pool with me, and I'm trying to issue AT Commands to it. Hyperterminal seems to be connecting to the specific port, but the device isn't responding to anything.

SMSCaster detects it as SIEMENS MC39i.

Any of you guys able to interface with this modem pool?

[image: Hyperterminal screenshot. No reply from device.]

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/16-port-wavecom-gsm-modem-usb_1832724495.html?s=p[image: 16 Port GSM Modem Pool USB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work the problem is to set the `Bits Per Second` setting to `115200`. It's now working perfectly.

[image]